# const [name, email, age] = req.body . TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

Tags: reactjs, database, mongodb, backend, mern

```
const app = express(); const mongoose = require('mongoose') const dotenv = require('dotenv') const User = require('./models/userModel'); dotenv.config(); app.use(express.json()) mongoose.connect(process.env.URI) .then(() => { console.log("connected to mongoDB successfully...") 
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8000, (err) => { if(err) console.log(err); console.log("Running successfully at ", process.env.PORT) }) }).catch((err) => { console.log("error: ", [error in console][1]err) }) //Create API app.post("/", async(req, res) => { const [name, email,age] = await req.body try { const userData = await User.create({ name: name, email: email, age: age, }); res.status(201).json(userAdded) } catch (error) { res.status(400).json({error:error.message}) } }) app.get('/', function(req, res){ res.send("This is working. THIS IS / endpoint") })
```

It is not connecting with mongodb server.

Comment: `const { name, email, age } = await req.body`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 2 main issues with your code. Let's address the first one before you fix your `TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`

Firstly, in your code you have:

```
const [name, email,age] = await req.body
```

There is no need to use the the `await` keyword here.

> Using await pauses the execution of its surrounding async function until the promise is settled (that is, fulfilled or rejected). When execution resumes, the value of the await expression becomes that of the fulfilled promise.

Since you are not waiting for a promise to settle you can remove that `await` keyword.

Secondly, you are using [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) but you have used it in the context of `req.body` being an array, but `req.body` is an object. You need to use:

```
 const {name, email, age} = req.body
```

To illustrate the difference. In a form submission `req.body` may look like this:

```
{
//...
   body:{ 
      name: 'bob', 
      email: 'bob@mail.com',
      age: 60
   }
//...
}
```

But because you have used `const [name, email,age]`, the destructuring assignment syntax is expecting to see something like this:

```
{
//...
   body:[ 
      'bob', 
      'bob@mail.com',
      60
   ]
//...
}
```

That's why you are getting the `TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))`. JavaScript Objects don't have a `@@iterator method`. Arrays do.

> Some built-in types have a default iteration behavior, while other types (such as Object) do not.

Comment: Thank you for your help with my code. I was stuck on this problem for a long time, but now my code is running perfectly thanks to you.